# How to remove these comments and html tags from the content?

Tags: comments, tags, editor, visual-editor

[image]

These are actually input fields.
paragraph is the textarea field.
i query the contents from database and try to show them in this textarea field.
But the textarea field is showing me unwanted comments and tags.
When I echo them outtside the textarea field, it is fine.

My code....

```
 <?php while($userNotes->have_posts()): $userNotes->the_post(); ?>

    <li>
        <input value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title()); ?>" class="note-title-field">

        <span class="edit-note"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</span>

        <span class="delete-note"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete</span>

        <textarea class="note-body-field"><?php echo esc_attr(get_the_content()); ?></textarea>

    </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: What can you see when you goto edit post?

Comment: You see tags because of `esc_attr()` applied to the post content. If you strip tags from content, you lost text formatting ability from editor (bold, italic, paragraph, etc.).

Comment: even if i remove esc_attr(), it shows same... I used strip_tags() and it worked but text formatting is lost.. Is there any perfect solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try this php function `html_entity_decode(get_the_content());`. I have used this function on php to remove html tags, you can try this.

Comment: This fuinction doesn't remove tags, it just changes the entities.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
<textarea class="note-body-field"><?php echo sanitize_text_field(get_the_content()); ?>
</textarea>
```

I'm also a beginner, but found this works in the frontend.
And it seems to be intended for similar use cases - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/

Comment: Please explain how that would remove the comments.